# Edit two models in one form

Tags: python, django, forms

I extended the standard `User` model of Django as described in the [Django
documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) to add some fields.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now I'd like to have a single form to edit fields from both models at the same
time. I found [this solution](http://chriskief.com/2012/12/30/django-class-based-views-with-multiple-forms/), but as far as I understand, this will result
in two forms with two submit buttons.

Is it possible to use Generic Class Based Views (UpdateView) to combine two models
in one form?  Or do I perhaps have to use a Function Based View?  What could such
a view look like?

**Edit**:

Saving data to both models works now. But I can't figure out how to load the data from the database for both models. My View now looks like this:

```
def UserSettingsUpdateView(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data

    user = request.user
    employee = user.employee

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = UserSettingsForm(request.POST)

        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():

            # Save User model fields
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.save()

            # Save Employee model fields
            employee.company = request.POST['company']
            employee.news_notifications = request.POST['news_notifications']
            employee.save() 

            # redirect to the index page
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    # if a GET (or any other method)
    else:
        form = UserSettingsForm(instance=user)

    return render(request, 'settings.html', {'form': form})
```

And my Form:

```
class UserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # fields from User model
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Last Name')

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'news_notifications',)
```

I think I have to pass the instance correkt to the form. But how can I do this for both models?

Thanks a lot again!

**2nd Edit**:

I found a solution:

```
def UserSettingsUpdateView(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data

    user = request.user
    employee = user.employee

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form_user = UserSettingsForm(request.POST)
        form_extended = UserSettingsExtendedForm(request.POST)

        # check whether it's valid:
        if form_user.is_valid() and form_extended.is_valid():

            # Save User model fields
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.save()

            # Save Employee model fields
            employee.company = request.POST['company']
            if "news_notifications" in request.POST:
                employee.news_notifications = True
            else:
                employee.news_notifications = False
            employee.save() 

            # redirect to the index page
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form_user = UserSettingsForm(instance=user)
        form_extended = UserSettingsExtendedForm(instance=employee)

    return render(request, 'settings.html', {'form_user': form_user, 'form_extended': form_extended})
```

And the forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from usersettings.models import Employee


class UserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)


class UserSettingsExtendedForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('company', 'news_notifications',)
```

And in the template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form_user|crispy }}
    {{ form_extended|crispy }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this solution:

mix two form like this:

```
class EmployeeEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #fields from User model that you want to edit
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_('First Name'))
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_('Last Name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'company')
```

Then, in `views.py` you can get `Employee` and `User` objects like this:

```
user = request.user
employee = user.employee
```

And edit `User` object like this:

```
user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
user.save()
```

And edit `Employee` object like this:

```
employee.company = request.POST['company']
employee.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Hasan! Saving data to both models works now, but I can't manage to load data from both models from the database in the form, see my edit above... Thanks again and kind regards from Germany!

Answer (score -1):

Try the user model at this [project template](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django). Once you understand how it works it's easier to hand the users. That template already comes with a form for what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

I saw all your answers, and I saw, that you solved this problem, but don't solved setting values to custom fields from database.

I have two models: default django's User and my Profile.
So I need to edit both of them in one form.
Here is my code:

view.py

```
def user_profile(request):
    profile_instance, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user) 
    profile_combined_form = ProfileCombinedForm(request.POST or None, instance=profile_instance)
    if request.POST:
        if profile_combined_form.is_valid():
                profile_combined_form.save_all_fields_from_request(request=request)
    return render(request, 'form-elements.html', {'form': profile_combined_form})
```

forms.py - combined form class

```
class ProfileCombinedForm(ModelForm):
    # fields from User model that you want to edit
    first_name = CharField(required=False, label='First Name')
    last_name = CharField(required=False, label='Last Name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileCombinedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        # You can dynamically adjust your layout
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save', 'Save'))
        self.fields['first_name'] = CharField(initial=self.instance.user.first_name)
        self.fields['last_name'] = CharField(initial=self.instance.user.last_name)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('balance', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save_all_fields_from_request(self, request):
        self.save()
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(id=request.user.id)
        user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        user.save()
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    balance = models.IntegerField( default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=False, null=False)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name
```

Now first_name and last_name correctly load from database and correctly save to database. Other fields(like 'balance') from Profile load and save correctly too.